# Can you retry Treat Wounds right away if it fails?

Tags: pathfinder-2e

The action [Treat Wounds](https://2e.aonprd.com/Actions.aspx?ID=57) says:

> You spend 10 minutes treating one injured living creature (targeting yourself, if you so choose). The target is then temporarily immune to Treat Wounds actions for 1 hour, but this interval overlaps with the time you spent treating (so a patient can be treated once per hour, not once per 70 minutes) [...]
>
> If you succeed at your check, you can continue treating the target to grant additional healing. If you treat them for a total of 1 hour, double the Hit Points they regain from Treat Wounds.

If you use Treat Wounds and fail, can you immediately retry?  Or does the "one hour temporarily immune to Treat Wounds" happen even if you fail?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

### The 1-hour immunity applies whether you succeed or fail

As written, the target becoming immune happens before you roll your check and thus cannot possibly depend on the result. There is nothing in this description that even remotely suggests otherwise.

If the intention were for it to work differently, there was a ton of clearer ways to word it.